# calling php with jquery file using jquery code

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Edited: 
I am trying to follow this [pagination tutorial](http://web.enavu.com/demos/paginate/). I already made it work.  However when I'm trying to load it through calling the php file(pagination), the jquery in the tutorial is not working.  Do you have any idea why?

Comment: -1: Please include a relevant snippet of what you're trying to do, otherwise it's not really possible to see where the problem is...

Comment: sorry. I edited my entry question. I hope someone can visualize what Im trying to know here.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function ajax_loadpage(loadUrl,output_container)
    {
        $.post
        (
            loadUrl,
            {language: "php", version: 5},function(responseText){$(output_container).html(responseText);},"html"
        );
    }

ajax_loadpage("url1.php","#div_wrapper_or_container");
</script>
```